# runtime replication

Tags: mysql, replication, multi-master, master-slave-replication

We have a master-master replication setup with 3 databases being replicated between both masters; 'database a', 'database b', 'database c'. Replication is row-based.

'database c' had an issue and we created a copy of it named 'database c-2' on master 1. We would like to:

1. replicate 'database c-2' to master 2.
2. Once replication is confirmed, we remove 'database c'
3. rename 'database c-2' to 'database c'

**2 Questions:**

- Is it possible to achieve this without restarting the mysql service ?
- Is it possible to rename a currently replicated database on the fly without breaking replication ?

Thanks in advance.

J

Answer (score 0):

Probably not as you describe.

On the Master with c-2:

- USE c;  -- So that replication knows that the following should be replicated.
- Foreach table `t` in database c-2:
  ** DROP TABLE c.t;
  ** CREATE TABLE c.t LIKE c-2.t;
  ** INSERT INTO c.t SELECT * FROM c-2.t;

Eventually DROP DATABASE c-2;

True, this does not give you the safety window.  And this blocks usage of each table as it is rebuilt.